# Why searchview causing app to crash in android studio?

Tags: android, searchview

I am attempting to implement a search view into my android application action bar (I will be using Parse to store the data). I have followed google's, and a few other tutorials I found online and it will not work. Every time I attempt to start the app in the `Android Studio` it crashes without opening and it emulator says that unfortunately, the app has stopped. (it worked fine before without the searchview).

**Main2Activity.java**

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SearchView;
    import android.content.Intent;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
        DatabaseHelper db ;
        ArrayList<String> listItem;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        ListView listwine;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

            listItem = new ArrayList<>();

            listwine = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wine_list);

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("EOΣΣ mobile"); // for set actionbar title
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // for add back arrow in action bar


            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
            mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
            mToggle.syncState();
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new
                        Home_Fragment()).commit();
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
            }

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        }





        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {



            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            new Home_Fragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_dry_wine:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            new Dry_wineFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_semi_dry:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new
                            Semi_dry_wineFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_sweet_dry:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            new Sweet_wineFragment()).commit();
                    break;

            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


            return true;


        }








       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);


            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();





          Cursor cursor = db.viewData();
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "No data to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    listItem.add(cursor.getString(1));     //index 1 is name index 0 is id
                }
            }


            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                  //  adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                    return true;

                }


            });

            //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

          return true;

        }

    }
```

**menu_search.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="Item 1"
            app:showAsAction="never" />



        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_search"
            android:title="menuSearch"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"


            app:showAsAction="always"
            app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
            />
    </menu>
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DB_NAME = "All_wine.db";
        private static final String DB_TABLE = "all_wine_table";
        private static final String DB_TABLE1 = "sweet_wine_table";
        private static final String DB_TABLE2 = "semi_dry_wine_Table";
        private static final String DB_TABLE3 = "dry_wine_Table";
        private static final String DB_TABLE4 = "English_all_wine";
        //columns
        private static final String  ID = "ID";
        private static final String NAME ="NAME";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE+"  ("+
               ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 ="CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE1+"  ("+
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE2 ="CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE2+"  ("+
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE3 ="CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE3+"  ("+
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE4 ="CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE4+"  ("+
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,DB_NAME ,null,1);

        }

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factoty, int version) {
            super(context,DB_NAME ,null,1);

        }

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factoty, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
            super(context,DB_NAME ,null,1);

        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +DB_TABLE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Grand Gru')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Vin Dux')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Athemis')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Nectar')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Φυλλάς')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Εκκλησιαστικός Οίνος')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Aegean Breeze(semi-dry)')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Selana')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Μοσχάτο Ασπρό')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Ψηλές Κορφές')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Aegean Breeze(dry)')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samena')");




            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +DB_TABLE1 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE1  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Grand Gru')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE1  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Vin Dux')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE1  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Athemis')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE1  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Nectar')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE1  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Φυλλάς')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE1  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Εκκλησιαστικός Οίνος')");


            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +DB_TABLE2 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE2  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Aegean Breeze(semi-dry)')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE2 + "(NAME) VALUES ('Selana')");


            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +DB_TABLE3 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");


            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE3  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Μοσχάτο Ασπρό')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE3  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Ψηλές Κορφές')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE3  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Aegean Breeze(dry)')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE3  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samena')");


            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +DB_TABLE4 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Grand Gru')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Vin Dux')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Athemis')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Nectar')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samos Φυλλάς')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Εκκλησιαστικός Οίνος')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Aegean Breeze(semi-dry)')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Selana')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Μοσχάτο Ασπρό')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Ψηλές Κορφές')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Aegean Breeze(dry)')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +DB_TABLE  + "(NAME) VALUES ('Samena')");






        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i ,int i1) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_TABLE);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_TABLE1);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_TABLE2);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_TABLE3);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_TABLE4);


            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

        }







        //create method  to view data
       public Cursor viewData(){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            return cursor;
        }




        //create method  to view data
        public Cursor viewData1(){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE1;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            return cursor;

        }


        //create method  to view data
        public Cursor viewData2(){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE2;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            return cursor;
        }


        //create method  to view data
        public Cursor viewData3(){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE3;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            return cursor;
        }


        //create method  to view data
        public Cursor viewData4(){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE4;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return cursor;
        }





        public List<String> getwine() {
            SQLiteDatabase  db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+DB_TABLE, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            return list;
        }


    }
```

**Error Log**

```
    08-06 14:27:43.169 497-497/? E/libsuspend: Error opening /sys/power/wakeup_count: Permission denied
    08-06 14:27:43.899 497-572/? E/libsuspend: Error opening /sys/power/wakeup_count: Permission denied
    08-06 14:27:44.369 497-544/? E/WifiHW: Unable to open connection to supplicant on "@android:wpa_eth1": No such file or directory
    08-06 14:27:47.729 156-450/? E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (No such file or directory)
    08-06 14:27:59.365 679-679/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.NotificationChannelGroup', referenced from method xji.a
    08-06 14:28:08.565 1171-1302/? E/Finsky: [89] com.google.android.finsky.setup.ao.a(92): Error prefetching preloads, using account=null, preloads=NULL, preloadGroups=NULL
        com.google.android.finsky.setup.fetchers.RawDocumentsFetchException[reason=pai_config, account=null]
            at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ao.a(SourceFile:47)
            at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ap.call(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    08-06 14:28:09.145 800-1318/? E/MDM: [85] whz.a: No Google accounts; deferring server state update.
    08-06 14:28:10.195 1371-1371/? E/UpdateRequestReceiver: ignoring update request
    08-06 14:28:10.195 1371-1371/? E/UpdateRequestReceiver: ignoring update request
    08-06 14:28:10.205 1371-1371/? E/UpdateRequestReceiver: ignoring update request
    08-06 14:28:10.205 1371-1371/? E/UpdateRequestReceiver: ignoring update request
    08-06 14:28:10.215 1371-1371/? E/UpdateRequestReceiver: ignoring update request
    08-06 14:28:10.215 1371-1371/? E/UpdateRequestReceiver: ignoring update request
    08-06 14:28:18.785 1171-1254/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.setup.a.a
    08-06 14:28:21.725 156-450/? E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (No such file or directory)
    08-06 14:58:43.522 156-450/? E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Those logs are unrelated to your crash. You're looking for [the stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), which should be a large section of red lines, starting with `FATAL EXCEPTION`. You can use the filters above the log window to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

Check Your Project is Androidx or Android
Because in Code Import is

```
import android.widget.SearchView;
```

Not Androidx(`import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;`) but in Xml you define

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

Both must be Android or AndroidX
 [Migration Doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: My project is androidx.What should l to fix it?

Comment: Change all imprts to AndroidX check doc you need to change gradle dependencies https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings